# Cost/benefit of multi-threaded text processing

Tags: c, objective-c, multithreading

I am working on a real-time syntax highlighter for the iPhone and I have created a custom UIView that takes a string, parses it and then highlights it in its drawRect: method. I've also implemented a blinking cursor. However, it is starting to get a little slow and I think that when I implement multi-line processing and chunk-processing, it will slow it down more. However, I tried placing the `[formattedTextView setNeedsDisplayInRect:]` call in a function in my view controller and then calling on a separate thread using `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateDisplay) withObject:nil]`. The keyboard is more responsive now, but this seems like a bad use of threads on a single-core processor.

Are there any problems with doing something like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out yourself, on a single processor multithreading will not bring a huge performance boost, but will come with a stability and complexity penalty.

On-the-fly Syntax-coloring is a hard problem, stuffed with possibilites for optimization:

- Are you applying a bunch of Regexes on the whole text? (bad) or do you parse the text to be held in an efficient datastructure like an ast?
- Are you limiting the colorized painting to the visible area?

Comment: I ended up removing the background-processing because it was causing a delay if many characters were typed in quick succession.

As for your other points:
- I am applying the regexes to the currently editable line.
- I only update the current line by calling setNeedsDisplayInRect:, the rest of the UIView stays colored.

It seems to me that the main cause of the slowdown is the blinking cursor (a CALayer with a CABasicAnimation set up in awakeFromNib) is there some way to optimize this animation?

Also, what is an ast? I haven't heard of that before, I'm using a NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 0):

> I am working on a real-time syntax highlighter

Are you doing keyword highlighting or have you written a BNF parser?

For the latter, why not have it running in a thread; the GUI simply displays the colouring of all that's been decoded so far.  That way you get instant update but delayed colouring.

Comment: I'm doing keyword highlighting with regular expressions, an actual parser would be nice, but I'm not sure I can write one.

Thanks,
Kyle

Comment: A BNF parser is much easier than you think - it's a conceptual leap that's required, where you need to get your brain round the basic concept - the actual coding is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Are you aware of any code/articles that would help me get my brain around the concept? Because a parser would be far superior to mere keyword highlighting. Thanks